# Django simplejwt + django-allauth how to issue personal access token for social media authentication

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, dj-rest-auth

I'm implementing a service that allows users to sign up via normal username + password, google, facebook and github. I have the authentication working on my decoupled frontend and backend, but here's my issue.

I am developing some python CLI tool which uploads data to the backend, but users must be authenticated to do so. I have had no issue authenticated users via the normal username + password endpoint, but i'm struggling to see how to achieve this with the social media authentication.

I have been thinking that users should be able to issue personal access tokens via the frontend (similar to github's personal access token), but my question would be how can I do that? I would imagine this requires extending the login endpoint for django-simplejwt package?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this tutorial : https://studygyaan.com/django/how-to-add-social-login-to-django . It is a good one, and it allows you to have oauth available with multiple instances simultaneously (facebook, twitter, etc...), and with a normal register/connection as well.